# What is the most efficient way to load my stored JPG file into the ImageView?

Tags: android, load, imageview, jpeg

I have valid JPG files and now I want to load them into a layout containing an ImageView.  I have code to findViewId(R.id.myimage).  I followed some sample code using File but it did not work.  The file is stored at /data/data/com.myapp/files/someimage.jpg.

What is the easiest and efficient way to load and display?

Comment: Please post the code that "did not work", and explain what error you encountered.

Comment: The code was essentially the code answered by Kevin Gaudin below, but I had the wrong ImageView id (to another layout, not the active context).  The error was a null pointer that I thought was for the bitmap and drawable :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/data/data/com.myapp/files/someimage.jpg"));
```

With the few info you give that's all I can do.

Comment: Very useful when I needed it in a hurry - thanks. Worked first time perfectly.